# Nx - Do apps importing libs use the build artefacts or just bundle?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm trying to understand how distributed builds work with Nx. If I have demo-app, and demo-lib, and demo-lib is not buildable, then the build time for demo-app, roughly, is the build time for demo-app plus the build time for demo-lib, as it all gets bundled at once, no cache.

If however, demo-lib is buildable, then demo-lib creates artefacts. If demo-lib does not change, and I build demo-app, then the build time is just build time for demo-app, as demo-lib does not build, it's cached.

Is this true? It seems like the tsconfig paths still just refer to the underlying source code, not the artefact. Therefore, when tsconfig paths plugin kicks in, and i build demo-app, is that not just going to bundle in demo-lib and have to do all the bundling for that code too, ultimately not saving me any build time?

I assume I've misunderstood so I'd appreciate an explanation as to how it works.

I guess my real question is, in an application with buildable libs that have no intent of being published - what are the build artefacts even used for?